# ADO Entity hierarchical self referencing

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, entity

I have a self referencing table named categories that has a parentcategoryid column that is nullable.

When I added the table to the entity designer it created two navigation properties for this relationship and I named one ParentCategory (the zero or 1 nav prop) and the other I named SubCategories (the * many nav prop).

Everything works great except when I go more than one level deep it doesn't pick up the deeper levels.

So I get all the Category.SubCategories but I don't get the categories under the subcategories.

Am I missing something? starting to think I should have stuck with NHibernate.  Shouldn't the deeper levels get lazy loaded?

```
    return from c in _entities.ContentCategorySet.Include("SubCategories")       
           where c.ParentCategory == null
           orderby c.Importance, c.Title
           select c;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I would Imagine the SubCategories property to behave.

Level 1

++ Level 2

++ Level 2

++ ++ Level 3

Where SubCategories property of Level 1 only returns Level 2 items. Then to get to Level 3 you would access the consecutive Level 2 items, in a recursive method.

Comment: I guess you are right, I thought there should be some entity magic there but ya I'll have to build them myself.

Comment: I do already have a recursive method though.  The problem is that they other categories aren't loaded into the entity.  You are saying I need to go query for the deeper nodes to build the entity?

Just want to be sure I am understanding.  It seems like this should be something that can be lazy loaded.

Comment: Here is my linq

            return from c in _entities.ContentCategorySet.Include("SubCategories")       
                   where c.ParentCategory == null
                   orderby c.Importance, c.Title
                   select c;

Answer (score 1):

OK, At least part of the problem is

```
where c.ParentCategory == null
```

When I remove that I get the deeper levels but then have subcategories on the top level.  I guess I can just filter them out after the fact.